# error post contact form 7 when use the woocommerce filter 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use this code snippet to below in order to disable Payment Gateway For Specific Shipping Method. 
Snippet found here : https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-payment-gateway-for-specific-shipping-method/

```
function bbloomer_gateway_disable_shipping_30( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;

  $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

$chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'local_pickup' ) ) {
unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
}
if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'local_pickup' ) ) {
unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
}
if ( isset( $available_gateways['stripe'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'local_pickup' ) ) {
unset( $available_gateways['stripe'] );
}

return $available_gateways;


}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bbloomer_gateway_disable_shipping_30' );
```

This code triggers a 500 error with contact form 7

https://moebella24.ninapresotto.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/57004/feedback 500

Comment: Try enabling the [debug log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), test your code again, then look into the log and see if there are any PHP warning/error messages in there.

Comment: there is a hook `remove_bacs_from_thank_you_page`. from where does it come ?

Comment: Session get() underfined function